# Outlook timeout on an RDS Session

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-terminal-services, outlook-2010, rds

We are using a remote hosted Terminal Services Server with individual RDS Sessions for our Users.

Emails work fine during use, but if they leave their system for about an hour and go back to Outlook and click on the TO: button - to access the GAL, Outlook will bring up a message after a little while:

The connection to Microsoft Exchange is unavailable. Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action.

Clicking OK on the message and the clicking back on the TO: button it works fine.

This will also happen if sending an email straight away from leaving the system for while.

The TS Sessions are set to 2hr Timeout so it is not this, I have checked power settings for the NIC and HDD etc.

So I believe this has to be a setting on either the Exchange or TS Servers somewhere.

Is there a way to lengthen Outlook's Timeout or a "Keep alive" Outlook setting somewhere?

Details:

We have three TS Servers for load balance, running on Windows Server 2008. With the broker on another Server.

Exchange 2010.

On the RDS Desktops our users have Outlook 2010 with Cache mode turned off.